How to reduce storage space used in redshift serverless?
I have S3 bucket which contains parquet files which are not more than 20 MB in size (all parquets combined).
I'm loading these files into AWS Redshift serverless tables using COPY command.
But after they are loaded into the Redshift, I see that the storage space used is 46 GB in serverless dashboard
Is there any way to analyse why it's taking so much space and any tricks to reduce the storage used?
I'm certain than, no matter now compressed the parquet files are (doesn't have more than 20 rows in each parquet file when loaded into dataframe), there shouldn't be this much difference. 20 MB vs 46 GB.
COPY {table_name} from 's3_file_location' FORMAT AS PARQUET IAM_ROLE 'role_to_be_used';

redshift namespace

Is it just one table? How many columns? Redshift uses columnar storage (similar to Parquet) and each column uses 1MB blocks, so that can sometimes cause bloat, but 46GB sounds crazy high. Do you know how much storage was used before those tables were loaded?

No. Not just one table. It's 525 tables.
And even before the tables were loaded, even with the tables empty, it was showing 1.6 GB storage space used for the serverless namespace.

I've added the Redshift serverless namespace screenshot in the question @JohnRotenstein
